# Rendering a specific set of frames in one job

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I want to render every 2nd(or even) frame and every 5th frame that end in '5' is it possible to do that in one render job.....not very good at scripting but will take any advice I can get

Comment: can unchecking overwrite help, does blender check the directory before or after rendering

Comment: Can you please elaborate if you want to render either every second frame *or* every fifth frame – in which case Jan Matys' answer should help – or whether you're looking for a way to render frames 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, etc. at one go without having to set the ranges and the *Frame Step* in between?

Comment: to clarify I want to render in the first instance every even frame 2,4,6,8.... then I want to render every 5th frame that's ends in 5 so 5,15, 25.... and so forth.....can that be done in a single render job, I think I got the answer to the ends with 5 question though

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to make a sequence of renders and give the user the option to cancel the process through the UI at any given time?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/71454/60486) and [Render from -100 frame](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/224413/60486)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible loop over a list of the desired frames, set the correct frame and render it within a Python script.

I didn't manage to automatically enumerate frames according to the [Blender Output Panel documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/fi/dev/render/output/output.html#output-panel), so I set the filename manually for each frame and restore the original value afterwards.

The following script should render all even frames as well as all frames that end in a five.

```
import bpy

scene = bpy.context.scene
tmp_filename = scene.render.filepath

all_frames = range(scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end + 1)

for f in [f for f in all_frames if f%2 == 0 or f%10 == 5]:
    scene.frame_set(f)
    scene.render.filepath = '//frame_{:04d}'.format(f)  # frame_0000 etc.
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)

scene.render.filepath = tmp_filename
```

You can select the desired frames by list comprehension like above or use Python's [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) function.

The “render with script” approach will make Blender unresponsive during the job, but I think the operating system won't shut the process down unless you tell it to do so, i.e. click on the “Blender is not responding” dialog box.

Comment: ok thank u very much, this is also helpful though my need to multitask might make the script approach prohibitive, still good to have this option...much appreciated....but I feel manually rendering both sets with the suggestion of Jan for getting the "end with 5 frames" will be best..........again thanks much for the python approach will be useful for times I can fully dedicate the PC to rendering

Comment: ok I misunderstood something that was said the script works well in the background thanks much

Answer (score 0):

on the image below the green rectangle shows the settings of Your interest...

[image]

FrameStep 2(5) will render every 2nd(5th) image and by setting the StartFrame You will choose the desired stepping - if U want every frame ending with "5" then choose StartFrame=5  and FrameStep=10 so frames 5,15,25,35 etc will be rendered.

Also if U want to render only every 5th frame ending with "5" then choose the starting frame and FrameStep=50. So when You choose starting at 5, then frames 15,25,35 and 45 will be skipped and next one rendered will be 55. Hope this helps buddy.

Sincerely, Jan

Comment: this is helpful thanks at least I don't have to waste render time on duplicate renders of 10,20,30 and such, what I am try to do is render a sequence like such "2,4,5,6,8,10,12,14,15,16....." and wanted to know if it could be done in one shot, but at least my duplication problem is solved even if I have to do two render jobs thanks

Comment: Ouch, I didnt understand it right as it looks. Still happy its helpful somehow ;).