# Multiple renders issues: render_pre handler do not set render borders before rendering

Tags: python, rendering

I am doing multiple renders using this template:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/71830/66604.

1. Method 'pre' should be executed before every render - and it is, for example then I am setting render file path in this method. But then I am setting render.border_max_x it has no effect on this render, only for next one. Why? Can it be fixed?
2. Perhaps this whole template can be done much simpler using [peisistent](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_8/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.persistent) handler?

Comment: Hi. Questions one and two sound like separate issues and should therefore be asked as separate questions. I suggest editing your post down to one question and asking the second separately.

Comment: Ok. Edited as suggested.