# How to interrupt a rendering which is not displayed in the UI to interact with?

Tags: python, rendering, operator

I created a script that renders and saves the selected objects. The script is quite large and I don't think it is necessary to post it completely.

```
def myRenderFunction(self,context):
    for o in context.selected_objects:
        ###some coordinates for camera position
        ###some functions to hide
        myPath = "C\:blah blah" + os.sep + o.name
        data_blocks = {o}
        bpy.data.libraries.write(myPath+".blend", data_blocks)
        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
        context.scene.render.filepath = myPath
```

My issue is that I can't find a way to stop it once executed because Blender's Interface is completely frozen while rendering the images.

**Q:** How can I allow the user to stop the rendering process at any given time?

Comment: @RayMairlot  Thank you very much for reporting, I was looking at this link first, but in fact my script is inside a for loop, and I found that the situation is slightly different

Comment: You want to allow the user hitting a button to abort the rendering process right? If that's your goal, you have to use a *modal operator*, which leads directly to the linked answer (it's is a hack anyway). Try to understand the answer and also have a look into the modal operator template... Or is there something I didn't understand? @Pastrokkio

Comment: @brockmann Ty , The problem is that I tried with the modal operator, but I don't know how to place the exit from the loop, I tried to insert the for loop inside the modal, but it remains frozen anyway, for days now I have stopped at the pole of the questions, I'm really frustrated because all the questions and answers I found don't solve my problem, I just want to understand how to place that for loop inside a modal operator correctly. This is not explained in any answer (or at least I have not found) For me these concepts are still little known, so I asked the specific question

Comment: Yeah, but it's a really broad question and takes a lot of effort to make it work (and testing all that stuff, also your question is incomplete IMO). I'd suggest split up the process into 2 operators, one for rendering (based on the linked code) and another one for loading the objects and to execute the rendering operator (the linked operator is basically a wrapper for `render.render()` allowing the user to exit).

Comment: @brockmann I guess it's not easy, and I thank you for the answers, I can put that function where I want, I can even insert it completely in modal uperator (which I've already done without success) my code is really too long to be posted here, basically the crucial point is this that I posted, I can handle it in any way, the important thing is that itineri on those objects, as they are manipulated during the loop for. I apologize for the headache question.

Comment: Minor code changes to make it work: https://pastecode.xyz/view/e10a812a However, it's just a starting point @Pastrokkio

Comment: @brockmann Thanks, I saw this link today, but I really don't know how to integrate my script into those scripts, I tried this afternoon with modal time operator, but I don't really understand how to integrate it, and then I noticed that the time only acts as a loop, so until the loop is finished you can't get out of that event (from what I've tried)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Minor code changes are required to make the [code from the linked answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/71830/31447) work for objects in selection.*

Following *modal operator* is just some kind of barebone code, a good starting point using the `timer` though. Edit the *render path* according to your *Operating System*, run the script, select the objects in *3d view*, press <kbd>F3</kbd> and type `Render multi...`

```
import bpy

class Multi_Render(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Docstring"""
    bl_idname = "render.multi"
    bl_label = "Render multiple times"

    # Define some variables to register
    _timer = None
    shots = None
    stop = None
    rendering = None
    path = "/tmp/"       # Linux
    #path = "C:\\tmp\\"  # Windows

    # Define the handler functions. I use pre and
    # post to know if Blender "is rendering"
    def pre(self, dummy):
        self.rendering = True

    def post(self, dummy):
        self.shots.pop(0) # Remove current object from list
                          # Render next Object 
        self.rendering = False

    def cancelled(self, dummy):
        self.stop = True

    def execute(self, context):
        # Define the variables during execution. This allows
        # to define when called from a button
        self.stop = False
        self.rendering = False

        # One shot per selected object
        self.shots = [o.name for o in context.selected_objects]

        context.scene.render.filepath = self.path

        bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(self.pre)
        bpy.app.handlers.render_post.append(self.post)
        bpy.app.handlers.render_cancel.append(self.cancelled)

        # The timer gets created and the modal handler
        # is added to the window manager
        self._timer = context.window_manager.event_timer_add(0.5, window=context.window)
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)

        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'TIMER': # This event is signaled every half a second
                                  # and will start the render if available

            # If cancelled or no more shots to render, finish.
            if True in (not self.shots, self.stop is True): 

                # We remove the handlers and the modal timer to clean everything
                bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.remove(self.pre)
                bpy.app.handlers.render_post.remove(self.post)
                bpy.app.handlers.render_cancel.remove(self.cancelled)
                context.window_manager.event_timer_remove(self._timer)

                return {"FINISHED"} # I didn't separate the cancel and finish
                                    # events, because in my case I don't need to,
                                    # but you can create them as you need

            elif self.rendering is False: # Nothing is currently rendering.
                                          # Proceed to render.
                sc = context.scene

                # I'm using cameras named just as the output files,
                # but adapt to your needs
                #sc.camera = bpy.data.objects[self.shots[0]]

                sc.render.filepath = self.path + self.shots[0]
                bpy.ops.render.render("INVOKE_DEFAULT", write_still=True)

        return {"PASS_THROUGH"}
        # This is very important! If we used "RUNNING_MODAL", this new modal function
        # would prevent the use of the X button to cancel rendering, because this
        # button is managed by the modal function of the render operator,
        # not this new operator!


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Multi_Render)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Multi_Render)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    #bpy.ops.render.multi('INVOKE_DEFAULT') # Test call
```

**Note:** You don't necessarily have to use a `for-loop`, the `post` method removes each item from the list in case the rendering is finished. Also I suggest split up the process into 2 *operators*, one for rendering only and another one to manage the whole process.

---

In case *you don't want the render window to show up* for whatever reason, you can either set the [`display_mode`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html?highlight=display_mode#bpy.types.RenderSettings.display_mode) to `'NONE'` temporary:

```
    elif self.rendering is False: # Nothing is currently rendering.
                                  # Proceed to render.
        sc = context.scene
        sc.render.display_mode = 'NONE'

        sc.render.filepath = self.path + self.shots[0]
        bpy.ops.render.render("INVOKE_DEFAULT", write_still=True)

        # Reset display mode
        sc.render.display_mode = 'WINDOW'
```

and add a check for the <kbd>ESC</kbd> event to remove the `timer`:

```
def modal(self, context, event):

    if event.type in {'ESC'}:
        context.window_manager.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
        bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.remove(self.pre)
        bpy.app.handlers.render_post.remove(self.post)
        bpy.app.handlers.render_cancel.remove(self.cancelled)

        self.report({'WARNING'}, 'User interuption')
        return {'FINISHED'}
    ...
```

*Or* you can call `render.render()` without `INVOKE_DEFAULT` to execute the operator directly (without the UI), e.g. based on a given variable (*notice that the progress bar does not show up*):

```
        if render_window:
            bpy.ops.render.render("INVOKE_DEFAULT", write_still=True)
        else:
            bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

---

Also you can add an `invoke()` method along with a `BoolProperty()` to the operator so the user can decide whether or not displaying the render window:

```
render_window: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
    name="Show Render Window",
    description="A bool property",
    default = False
)

def invoke(self, context, event): # Used for user interaction
    wm = context.window_manager
    return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)
```

and add a condition for that within the `modal` method (before rendering):

```
    elif self.rendering is False: # Nothing is currently rendering.
                                  # Proceed to render.
        sc = context.scene

        if self.render_window == False:
            sc.render.display_mode = 'NONE'

        sc.render.filepath = self.path + self.shots[0]
        bpy.ops.render.render("INVOKE_DEFAULT", write_still=True)

        # Reset display mode
        sc.render.display_mode = 'WINDOW'
```

[image]

*However, it is indeed tricky to make it work properly...*

Comment: I thank you for your time, how can I stop this with the esc button? because i not need the preview render windows

Comment: Thank you very much for the great effort, however I have taken inspiration from your phrase "It is not necessary to use a for loop" and in fact that was the trick, when you used the list of objects with the append function, I solved the blocking of the loop for. But I see that it's not easy to get out of the modal, sometimes it comes out and sometimes it's not a known blender problem?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about: You've got a list with all objects in selection right? Why appending something to that? It's already there and good to go. Anyway, to solve your second issue (1 out of 100 issues here) you can try to decrease the timer value, should make it easier getting out of *my modal* (not the loop) @Pastrokkio

Comment: The object selection context was just to simplify the question, in reality I have several variables that decide which items to put on the list, I think this doesn't change things much. The fact remains that getting out of the modal is always a bet ... I have to understand the context as I deal with different scenes.

Comment: Working here without any issues. You should have things sorted before rendering, maybe that's your issue... All I could imagine from reading your post plus some extra bits is already part of my answer so I don't know how to improve it even further  @Pastrokkio

Comment: Well, thank you, I confirm that I will proceed with the improvement of my script, if there will be further questions I will post new ones, I thank you very much and not "Dilago further" so this question has been answered.

Comment: Great example, thanks. I got it to work properly in Blender 2.8. ESC button event works as should be. But, now I'm struggling with: how I can stop render from another Operators button/function? So I want to stop rendering process by pressing custom button in Blender UI.

Comment: I think one simple way is adding a global boolean e.g. to the scene and ask for its current state in the same line as checking for the event like `if event.type in {'ESC'} and C.scene.your_bool_prop:` @SakariNiittymaa

Comment: @brockmann Yes! Thanks. Im still learning this. I solved this problem by creating `stop_rendering: BoolProperty()` and changing that property with other buttons operator `scene.render_settings.stop_rendering = True`, then just check its state same time with ESC event `scene.render_settings.stop_rendering is True`

Comment: Note that in newer versions of Blender you will need to add depsgraph as an argument to the handlers, eg.
def post(self, dummy, depsgraph):