# Using Blender's Python API "bpy.ops.render.render()", I can't see the rendering process, Blender will freeze suddenly

Tags: rendering

When I use Blender's Python API `bpy.ops.render.render()`, I can't see the rendering process. Blender will freeze suddenly, it will take some time to return the result.

How can I see the render process in the Blender terminal?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean Python Console by "Blender terminal", you cannot see progress there. You can [use Blender form command line directly to render](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/render.html). This way you will see messages about the progress in the Command Prompt/Powershell/Terminal window.

If you want to use `bpy.ops.render.render()` operator, but start it as if you pressed the button in Render menu so it shows rendering process in the UI, you have to change the operator's execution context, you can do it calling it like this: `bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT')`

Keep in mind that any code that you have after that will try to execute while rendering is starting(and probably produce unexpected results). You have to use `bpy.app.handlers.render_post` or `bpy.app.handlers.render_complete` handler to execute code after rendering process is complete. See this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/164012/60759