# Is it possible to render an animation sequence in python using INVOKE_DEFAULT?

Tags: python, add-on

i'm try to make an add-on that can render animation sequences.

If I just use a for loop to render every frame in sequence blender freezes completely until the job is finished.

`bpy.ops.render.render("INVOKE_DEFAULT")`

renders responsively but the script thinks it happened within a millisecond and the loop moves on to the next frame.

The

```
bpy.app.handlers.render_post
```

can detect when a render finishes, but I can't figure out how to use it in a loop with a user definable sequence length.

Operations are being done during rendering between the frames, updating values, so using

```
(animation=True)
```

won't work

Or if that's completely impossible, could I at least force UI updates to the add-on panel during rendering with

```
EXEC_DEFAULT
```

(I mainly want this so that my addon can show the progress percentage in a UI panel. Doing this from the console is not very pretty)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to make a sequence of renders and give the user the option to cancel the process through the UI at any given time?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71454/is-it-possible-to-make-a-sequence-of-renders-and-give-the-user-the-option-to-can)

Comment: it looks like that is just for rendering a few predefined frames

Comment: You can use application timers https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html

Comment: just a small notice: did you ever try loom? free add-on which can do a lot of automatic/batch rendering so maybe you wanna try that?

Answer (score 0):

If you render an image sequence, all you have to do is set your start/end frames as you need, and then use [`bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.render.html#bpy.ops.render.render).

Comment: hmm that sounds like i wouldnt be able to calculate the progress and estimated time remaining for every frame rendered for my ui panel.

Comment: Sure but you already have all the progress info you need in the render view already. What would be the purpose of performing a render in a less efficient way to show the info differently?

Comment: estimated time until the sequence is done rendering, as well as a feature i made that can resume interrupted renders due to crashes where the frame left off