# Blender Addon for rendering animation with multiple settings without freezes Blender UI

Tags: rendering, animation, add-on, operator

I am trying to write an addon that will give me an ability to set settings for multiple render sequences. I used to use `bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True, write_still=True)` function but it freezes the UI, then I used `bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT', animation=True, write_still=True)` but It does not work in a loop (cause it skips the order and renders the last ops call)

So I decided to use Modal Operator call to check if the render is active then do not call next render operator otherwise change the settings and call operator.
It seems to work but I just need your expert advice on how to make it better, less buggy.

If you can test it in your scenario or let me know what might need some fix I will be more than glad to implement it!

```
import bpy

class RenderSeqOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.render_seq_operator"
    bl_label = "Render Sequence Operator"
    
    index = 0
    list_of_renders = []
    
    def set_render_settings(self, rig_name, scene_name, cam_name, track_name, frame_start, frame_end, output_path):
        # Get the armature object
        if not rig_name:
            print("No armature selected!")
            return False
        
        armature_obj = bpy.data.objects[rig_name]
        if armature_obj.type != 'ARMATURE':
            print("Selected object is not an armature!")
            return False
            
        # Get the scene by name
        scene = bpy.data.scenes.get(scene_name)
        if scene is None:
            print(f"Scene '{scene_name}' not found!")
            return False

        # Set the current scene
        bpy.context.window.scene = scene

        # Mute all tracks
        for track in armature_obj.animation_data.nla_tracks:
            track.mute = True

        # Activate the specified track
        track_index = armature_obj.animation_data.nla_tracks.find(track_name)
        if track_index == -1:
            print(f"Track '{track_name}' not found!")
            return False

        armature_obj.animation_data.nla_tracks[track_index].mute = False
        
        #set the camera active
        cam_obj = bpy.data.objects[cam_name]
        if cam_obj.type != 'CAMERA':
            print("Selected object is not a camera!")
            return False
        bpy.context.scene.camera = cam_obj
        

        # Set the render frame range
        bpy.context.scene.frame_start = frame_start
        bpy.context.scene.frame_end = frame_end
        #bpy.context.scene.cycles.samples = samples
        bpy.context.scene.render.fps = 12
        bpy.context.scene.render.use_file_extension = True
        bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.color_mode = 'RGBA'

        # Set the render output path
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output_path
        
        return True
    
    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'ESC'}:
            return {'FINISHED'}
        
        if not bpy.app.is_job_running('RENDER'):
            if self.index < len(self.list_of_renders):
                #set render settings
                rig_name = self.list_of_renders[self.index][0]
                scene_name = self.list_of_renders[self.index][1]
                cam_name = self.list_of_renders[self.index][2]
                track_name = self.list_of_renders[self.index][3]
                frame_start = self.list_of_renders[self.index][4]
                frame_end = self.list_of_renders[self.index][5]
                output_path = self.list_of_renders[self.index][6]
                
                if not self.set_render_settings(rig_name, scene_name, cam_name, track_name, frame_start, frame_end, output_path):
                    return {'FINISHED'}
                # Call another instance of render with animation
                bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT', animation=True, write_still=True)
                RenderSeqOperator.index += 1
            else:
                print("Nothing to Render!")
                return {'FINISHED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        #set list of renders
        self.list_of_renders.append(["m2_rig", "m2","up", "walk_up", 0, 15, "C:/walk/up/"])
        self.list_of_renders.append(["m2_rig", "m2","down", "walk_down", 0, 15, "C:/walk/down/"])
        self.list_of_renders.append(["m2_rig", "m2","down", "idle_down", 0, 23, "C:/idle/down/"])
        #add modal
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

# Register the operator
def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(RenderSeqOperator.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(RenderSeqOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(RenderSeqOperator)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.remove(menu_func)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    # test call
    bpy.ops.object.render_seq_operator('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to my problem right here [Is it possible to make a sequence of renders and give the user the option to cancel the process through the UI at any given time?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71454/is-it-possible-to-make-a-sequence-of-renders-and-give-the-user-the-option-to-can)

It uses timers to check in modal function if render is complete or not

```
import bpy

class Multi_Render(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Docstring"""
    bl_idname = "render.multi"
    bl_label = "Render multiple times"
    
    # Define some variables to register
    _timer = None
    shots = []
    stop = None
    rendering = None
    
    #render settings function
    def set_render_settings(self, rig_name, scene_name, cam_name, track_name, frame_start, frame_end, output_path):
        # Get the armature object
        if not rig_name:
            print("No armature selected!")
            return False
        
        armature_obj = bpy.data.objects[rig_name]
        if armature_obj.type != 'ARMATURE':
            print("Selected object is not an armature!")
            return False
            
        # Get the scene by name
        scene = bpy.data.scenes.get(scene_name)
        if scene is None:
            print(f"Scene '{scene_name}' not found!")
            return False

        # Set the current scene
        bpy.context.window.scene = scene

        # Mute all tracks
        for track in armature_obj.animation_data.nla_tracks:
            track.mute = True

        # Activate the specified track
        track_index = armature_obj.animation_data.nla_tracks.find(track_name)
        if track_index == -1:
            print(f"Track '{track_name}' not found!")
            return False

        armature_obj.animation_data.nla_tracks[track_index].mute = False
        
        #set the camera active
        cam_obj = bpy.data.objects[cam_name]
        if cam_obj.type != 'CAMERA':
            print("Selected object is not a camera!")
            return False
        bpy.context.scene.camera = cam_obj
        

        # Set the render frame range
        bpy.context.scene.frame_start = frame_start
        bpy.context.scene.frame_end = frame_end
        #bpy.context.scene.cycles.samples = samples
        bpy.context.scene.render.fps = 12
        bpy.context.scene.render.use_file_extension = True
        bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.color_mode = 'RGBA'

        # Set the render output path
        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = output_path
        
        return True

    # Define the handler functions. I use pre and
    # complete to know if Blender "is rendering"
    def pre(self, scene, context=None):
        self.rendering = True
        
    def complete(self, scene, context=None):
        self.shots.pop(0) # This is just to render the next
                          # image in another path
        self.rendering = False

    def cancelled(self, scene, context=None):
        self.stop = True

    def execute(self, context):
        # Define the variables during execution. This allows
        # to define when called from a button
        self.stop = False
        self.rendering = False
        #set list of renders
        self.shots.append(["m2_rig", "m2","up", "walk_up", 0, 15, "C:/Users/mihail.lebedev/Downloads/VIZOR/PROJECTS/Atlantis/keepers/render/test/m2/walk/up/"])
        self.shots.append(["m2_rig", "m2","down", "walk_down", 0, 15, "C:/Users/mihail.lebedev/Downloads/VIZOR/PROJECTS/Atlantis/keepers/render/test/m2/walk/down/"])
        self.shots.append(["m2_rig", "m2","down", "idle_down", 0, 23, "C:/Users/mihail.lebedev/Downloads/VIZOR/PROJECTS/Atlantis/keepers/render/test/m2/idle/down/"])
        
        context.scene.render.filepath = self.path
        
        bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(self.pre)
        bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(self.complete)
        bpy.app.handlers.render_cancel.append(self.cancelled)
        
        # The timer gets created and the modal handler
        # is added to the window manager
        self._timer = context.window_manager.event_timer_add(0.5, window=context.window)
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}
        
    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type == 'TIMER': # This event is signaled every half a second
                                  # and will start the render if available
            
            # If cancelled or no more shots to render, finish.
            if True in (not self.shots, self.stop is True): 
                
                # We remove the handlers and the modal timer to clean everything
                bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.remove(self.pre)
                bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.remove(self.complete)
                bpy.app.handlers.render_cancel.remove(self.cancelled)
                context.window_manager.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
                
                return {"FINISHED"} # I didn't separate the cancel and finish
                                    # events, because in my case I don't need to,
                                    # but you can create them as you need
            
            elif self.rendering is False: # Nothing is currently rendering.
                                          # Proceed to render.
                #set render settings
                rig_name = self.shots[0][0]
                scene_name = self.shots[0][1]
                cam_name = self.shots[0][2]
                track_name = self.shots[0][3]
                frame_start = self.shots[0][4]
                frame_end = self.shots[0][5]
                output_path = self.shots[0][6]
                
                self.set_render_settings(rig_name, scene_name, cam_name, track_name, frame_start, frame_end, output_path)
                bpy.ops.render.render("INVOKE_DEFAULT", animation=True, write_still=True)

        return {"PASS_THROUGH"}
        # This is very important! If we used "RUNNING_MODAL", this new modal function
        # would prevent the use of the X button to cancel rendering, because this
        # button is managed by the modal function of the render operator,
        # not this new operator!

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Multi_Render)
 
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Multi_Render)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    
    bpy.ops.render.multi() # Test call
```