How to handle invalid context in Blender 4.0 after render
In my Python script, I rotate a randomized dice with a rigid body, play the animation using bpy.ops.screen.animation_play() to apply the physics, and then render the animation. After that, I start with the next randomized rotation of the dice.
If I render with bpy.ops.render.render(animation=True), the physics of the rigid body don't apply.
If I render with bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT', animation=True), an error appears during the second rotation at bpy.context.scene.frame_set(0) indicating that the context is invalid. It seems the context is still in the render window.
Here is the complete code:
python
import bpy
import random
import math
import csv
import os
from mathutils import Vector

seed = 0
wuerfels = ["dice"]
seeds = []#list(range(1, 100))
render_seeds = [17,25,27]
ergebnis_schreiben = False
renderer = False
pfad = 'C:\\dice'
wuerfeltyp = 'Rot'

def set_wuerfels(wuerfels):
    random.seed(seed)
    anz_wuerfels = len(wuerfels)
    for i, wuerfel in enumerate(wuerfels):
        wuerfelobj = bpy.data.objects[wuerfel]

        start_rot = [random.uniform(0, 6.2831853071795) for _ in range(3)]
        end_rot = [start_rot[i] + random.uniform(-1.745329251994329, 1.745329251994329) for i in range(3)]
        
        if anz_wuerfels == 3:
            y = i*3 -3
            y_start = random.uniform(-1,1) + y
            y_stop = random.uniform(-1,1) + y
        elif anz_wuerfels == 2:
            y = i*4 -2
            y_start = random.uniform(-1.5,1.5) + y
            y_stop = random.uniform(-1.5,1.5) + y
        elif anz_wuerfels == 1:
            y_start = random.uniform(-4,4)
            y_stop = random.uniform(-4,4)

        z_start = random.uniform(6,8)
        z_stop = random.uniform(7,9)
        
        wuerfelobj.location = [25, y_start, z_start]        
        wuerfelobj.rotation_euler = start_rot
        
        wuerfelobj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=0)
        wuerfelobj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=0)

        wuerfelobj.rotation_euler = end_rot
        wuerfelobj.location = [12, y_stop, z_stop]  
        wuerfelobj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rotation_euler", frame=10)
        wuerfelobj.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=10)




def evaluate_dice_roll(obj):
    # Erstelle einen temporären einfachen Würfel
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
    temp_cube = bpy.context.active_object
    
    # Setze den temporären Würfel auf die Position und Rotation des ursprünglichen Würfels
    temp_cube.matrix_world = obj.matrix_world
    
    # Update the mesh to ensure world coordinates are up to date
    temp_cube.data.update()
    
    max_z = float('-inf')
    top_face_index = -1

    for face in temp_cube.data.polygons:
        # Get the center of the face in world coordinates
        face_center = temp_cube.matrix_world @ face.center

        if face_center.z > max_z:
            max_z = face_center.z
            top_face_index = face.index

    # Lösche den temporären Würfel
    bpy.data.objects.remove(temp_cube, do_unlink=True)
    # Manuelle Zuordnung der Face-Indices zu den Würfelseiten
    face_values = {
        0: 2,  # Beispiel: Face-Index 0 entspricht Seite 6
        1: 3,  # Beispiel: Face-Index 1 entspricht Seite 1
        2: 5,  # Beispiel: Face-Index 2 entspricht Seite 5
        3: 4,  # Beispiel: Face-Index 3 entspricht Seite 2
        4: 1,  # Beispiel: Face-Index 4 entspricht Seite 3
        5: 6   # Beispiel: Face-Index 5 entspricht Seite 4
        # Weitere Zuordnungen können hier hinzugefügt werden, je nach Komplexität des Würfels
    }
    return face_values.get(top_face_index, 0)



def stop_animation_at_end_frame(scene):
    if scene.frame_current == scene.frame_end:
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()  # Stoppt die Animation
        bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.remove(stop_animation_at_end_frame)
        print("seed")
        print(seed)
        results = []
        for wuerfel in wuerfels:
            wuerfelobj = bpy.data.objects[wuerfel]
            roll_result = evaluate_dice_roll(wuerfelobj)
            results.append(roll_result)
        results.sort(reverse=True)
        print( results)
        if ergebnis_schreiben:
                # Schreibe das Ergebnis in eine CSV-Datei
            with open('C:\\dice_results_2er.csv', mode='a', newline='') as file:
                writer = csv.writer(file)
                writer.writerow([seed] + results)
            print(f"Ergebnisse wurden in 'dice_results.csv' geschrieben: {results}") 
        if seeds:
            search(seeds)
            
        if renderer:
            start_render(results)




def search(seeds):
    global seed, ergebnis_schreiben, renderer
    if seeds:
        seed = seeds.pop(0)
        print("akt_seed")
        print(seed) 
    else: 
        return
    if seed == 0:
        seed = random.randint(0, 9999999999999)
        print("Seed: " + str(seed))
    ergebnis_schreiben = True
    renderer  = False
    roll_the_dice()



def roll_the_dice():
    set_wuerfels(wuerfels)
    set_wuerfels(wuerfels)

    # Setze den aktuellen Frame auf 0
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(0)
    bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()




    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(stop_animation_at_end_frame)

def start_render(results):
    global c
    results_string = ''
    for x in results:
        results_string = results_string + "-" + str(x)
    results_string = results_string[1:]
    
    wurfpfad = pfad + "\\" + wuerfeltyp + "\\" + results_string + "\\" + str(seed)
    print(wurfpfad)
    
    if not os.path.exists(wurfpfad):
    # Wenn der Pfad nicht existiert, erstelle ihn
        os.makedirs(wurfpfad)
    wurfpfad = wurfpfad + "\\" + wuerfeltyp + "_r" + results_string + "_s" + str(seed) + "_"
    
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = wurfpfad

    bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.append(post_render)
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(0)
    bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_DEFAULT', animation=True)

    

def post_render(dummy):
    bpy.app.handlers.render_complete.remove(post_render)
    bpy.app.timers.register(shut_window, first_interval=10)
    
def shut_window():
    

    render_queue()
    return None    

def render_queue():
    global seed, ergebnis_schreiben, renderer
    
    ergebnis_schreiben = False
    renderer  = True
    if render_seeds:
        seed = render_seeds.pop(0)
        print("akt_seed render")
        print(seed) 
    else: 
        return
    
    roll_the_dice()
    
if seeds:
    search(seeds)
else:
    render_queue()

I'm using Blender 4.0.
Does anyone have an idea of how I can get this to work?

Hello and welcome. Can you include the backtrace error in your question?

Hello, I'd look at what set_wuerfels(wuerfels) does and if it doesn't have unintended side effects. eg reloading the scene or something like that. Alternatively you can access a scene regardless of the state of context if you know its name with bpy.data.scenes["Scene"]

You’ll probably have to bake the physics cache each time.

It's not after render, it's during. The code probably does not stop when render starts. If you want to render from a script and do stuff after you need to use a modal operator(unfortunately). See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/71830/60759

By the way, for future questions, it would really increase your chances of getting more specific help if you could post some code that can just be copy-pasted and run, because that way people don't need to spend time just to make it run. I mean just imagine how much people like to spend their time to just figure out what code you might have and writing it before attempting to help. ;)

Okay, I think I'm going crazy. Before posting, I spent 2 days looking for the error. I made the post, and afterwards, to copy the error message, I ran a few more test runs. And now it works. Just like that. Without any changes. I don't know what's different now compared to before.
Thank you very much for your help. I have included the entire code above again.

That's weird. The way I understand it, it shouldn't work reliably. I would test it carefully and a lot. It may work with renders that take specific amount of time, but not with others. It may have something to do with the timer you have there.
